Flux notifications for Teams in parallel to Slack notifications
SysAdmin wanted me to do the following:
We need to setup Flux notifications for Teams in parallel to Slack notifications. It's easier to add developers to Teams channels as they already have Teams account, while we will keep Slack notifications with a few users for redundancy reasons. Name of the channel - FluxCD notifications test/stage, it'll require a webhook setup so Flux can post to it. It needs to be set and I need the webhook endpoint.
How do I do this correctly?
Thanks!
Through Power Automate I did a trigger for "When a HTTP request is recieved" to action "Post a message in a chat or channel" but if I understand correctly, I need to set the payload for this to work?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you need to create an incoming webhook in Microsoft Teams. The complete guide can be found here. The channel should be chosen in this step. Then you can add the manifests for flux that is guided here.
As of August 15th, Microsoft is retiring Office 365 connectors in Teams and Workflows is the recommended alternative.
Use the "Post to a channel when a webhook request is received" workflow template:
Open the Teams app and navigate to the channel where you received notifications from the O365 connector.
Click on the "…" menu and select "Workflows."
Choose "Create" and then select "From a template."
Find the template called "Post to a channel when a webhook request is received."
Configure the Workflow:
In the workflow builder, you'll see the "When a HTTP request is received" trigger. You'll likely need to update the URL in the trigger to match the new endpoint provided by the workflow.
In the "Actions" section, choose "Microsoft Teams - Post message."
Configure the message content. You can use dynamic values here.
For example, to include the name, you might reference a key from your webhook data like ${body.name}.

Hey, thank you for your reply. The "problem" here is that Incoming Webhooks/Connections don't work anymore and are being taken out on August 15th so I must do it via Power Automate/Workflows and I'm lost

I see. I have added the new way too.

Thanks!
Now when I test it through postman, I get this:
{
"error": {
"code": "WorkflowTriggerIsNotEnabled",
"message": "Could not execute workflow '7df2635f-17e6-40ca-8331-1a091a24dcde' trigger 'manual' with state 'Suspended': trigger is not enabled."
}
}

Navigate to the flow and enable it (Turn on)
